# Efficiently update rows of a postgres table from another table in another database based on a condition in a common column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have two [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) [DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

`df1` from database A with connection parameters `{"host":"hostname_a","port": "5432", "dbname":"database_a", "user": "user_a", "password": "secret_a"}`. The column `key` is the primary key.

`df1`:

```
|    | key   | create_date  | update_date   |
|---:|------:|:-------------|:--------------|
|  0 | 57247 | 1976-07-29   | 2018-01-21    | 
|  1 | 57248 |              | 2018-01-21    | 
|  2 | 57249 | 1992-12-22   | 2016-01-31    | 
|  3 | 57250 |              | 2015-01-21    | 
|  4 | 57251 | 1991-12-23   | 2015-01-21    | 
|  5 | 57262 |              | 2015-01-21    | 
|  6 | 57263 |              | 2014-01-21    |
```

`df2` from database B with connection parameters `{"host": "hostname_b","port": "5433", "dbname":"database_b", "user": "user_b", "password": "secret_b"}`. The column `id` is the primary key (these values are originally the same than the one in the column `key` in `df1`; it's only a renaming of the primary key column of `df1`).

`df2`:

```
|    | id    | create_date  | update_date   | user  |
|---:|------:|:-------------|:--------------|:------|
|  0 | 57247 | 1976-07-29   | 2018-01-21    |       |
|  1 | 57248 |              | 2018-01-21    |       |
|  2 | 57249 | 1992-12-24   | 2020-10-11    | klm   |
|  3 | 57250 | 2001-07-14   | 2019-21-11    | ptl   |
|  4 | 57251 | 1991-12-23   | 2015-01-21    |       |
|  5 | 57262 |              | 2015-01-21    |       |
|  6 | 57263 |              | 2014-01-21    |       |
```

Notice that the row[2] and row[3] in `df2` have more recent `update_date` values (`2020-10-11` and `2019-21-11` respectively) than their counterpart in `df1` (where `id` = `key`) because their `creation_date` have been modified (by the given users).

I would like to update rows (i.e. in concrete terms; `create_date` and `update_date` values) of `df1` where `update_date` in `df2` is more recent than its original value in `df1` (for the same primary keys).

This is how I'm tackling this for the moment, using [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) + the [`.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)' [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connector = psycopg2.connect(**database_parameters_dictionary)
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://', creator=connector)
df1.update(df2) # 1) maybe there is something better to do here?
with engine.connect() as connection:
    df1.to_sql(
        name="database_table_name",
        con=connection,
        schema="public",
        if_exists="replace", # 2) maybe there is also something better to do here?
        index=True
    )
```

The problem I have is that, according to the documentation, the `if_exists` argument can only do three things:

> if_exists{‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’

Therefore, to update these two rows, I have to;
1) use [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) method on `df1` using `df2` as an argument, together with
2) replacing the whole table inside the [`.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method, which means "drop+recreate".
As the tables are really large (more than 500'000 entries), I have the feeling that this will need a lot of unnecessary work!

How could I efficiently update only those two newly updated rows? Do I have to generate some custom SQL queries to compares the dates for each rows and only take the ones that have really changed? But here again, I have the intuition that, looping through all rows to compare the update dates will take "a lot" of time. How is the more efficient way to do that? (It would have been easier in pure SQL if the two tables were on the same host/database but it's unfortunately not the case).

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can't do partial updates of a table, no. There is a [longstanding open bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14553) for supporting sub-whole-table-granularity updates in `.to_sql()`, but you can see from the discussion there that it's a very complex feature to support in the general case.

However, limiting it to just your situation, I think there's a reasonable approach you could take.

Instead of using `df1.update(df2)`, put together an expression that yields only the changed records with their new values (I don't use pandas often so I don't know this offhand); then iterate over the resulting dataframe and build the UPDATE statements yourself (or with the SQLAlchemy expression layer, if you're using that). Then, use the connection to DB A to issue all the UPDATEs as one transaction. With an indexed PK, it should be as fast as this would ever be expected to be.

BTW, I don't think df1.update(df2) is exactly correct - from my reading, that would update all rows with any differing fields, not just when updated_date > prev updated_date. But it's a moot point if updated_date in df2 is only ever more recent than those in df1.